# how to obtain a list in javascript from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

```
['string1', 'string2'].join(',') // "string1,string2"
```

How can I obtain the following result?

```
"string1", "string2"
```

I am using underscore and jquery.

My goal is to make something like that:

```
_.without(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'], "string1", "string2");
=> ['string3']
```

Comment: This is very confusing, it looks like you are trying to get what you already have...

Comment: Are you positive what you really want is a list? it looks like instead you want to pass arguments to a function, which a list would be useless for.

Comment: Not sure I get it, is [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgrC4/) it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you case you don't need a "free" list of elements.
You just need to use `_.difference` instead of `_.without`.

```
  _.difference(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'], ["string1", "string2"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a "free" list of elements. That's not how Javascript works. You always deal with arrays, collections and that sort of things.

I don't know Underscore.js very well, but try this:

```
var a = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
    b = ['string1', 'string2'];
_.without.apply(_, [a].concat(b));
```

The purpose of `apply` is to call a function with a dynamical number of dynamic arguments.

Comment: +1; further reading for the OP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

you could get it like this:

`var something = '"' + ['string1', 'string2'].join('", "') + '"';`

wich would result in: `"string1", "string2"`

alternately you could use `JSON.stringify(['string1', 'string2'])`

wich would result in: `["string1","string2"]`

Answer (score 0):

another way is to write a simple function which removes an array of strings from another, sth like

```
var arr = ["str1","str2","str3"];

   function removeStrings(a,strs) {
     strs.forEach(function(e) {
       a.splice(a.indexOf(e),1);
     });
   }

removeStrings(arr,["str2","str1"]);
console.log(arr);//["str3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

difference looks like better fit
http://underscorejs.org/#difference

```
var rem, orig, val;
rem = ['string1', 'string2'];
orig = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];

val = _.difference(orig, rem); // ['string3'];
```

http://jsbin.com/eyegoh/1/edit

or little bit longer with jQuery using
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
var rem, orig, val;
rem = ['string1', 'string2'];
orig = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];

val = $.grep(orig, function(el, ix) {
    return $.inArray(el, rem) == -1;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uhihid/1/edit